# Generate random ENUM value [PHP, MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that consists of a few fields with different data types. **My task is to create a PHP script that fills this table with a random data**. My script will consist of looped MySQL queries. I know how to create a query for generating random *date*, *integer* and *string*.

I have a column that uses **ENUM** data type that has 4 values ('accepted', 'with errors', 'done', 'failed').

I need to know how to **generate a query that allows me to fill in the ENUM field with a random value.**

If anyone helps, I would **greatly** appreciate.

p.s. If my question is too dumb or not clear enough, I apologize for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Shorter way using Enum:

```
enum Status: string
{
    case ACCEPTED = "accepted";
    case WITH_ERRORS = "with errors";
    case DONE = "done";
    case FAILED ='failed';

    public static function randomValue(): string
    {
        $arr = array_column(self::cases(), 'value');

        return $arr[array_rand($arr)];
    }

    public static function randomName(): string
    {
        $arr = array_column(self::cases(), 'name');

        return $arr[array_rand($arr)];
    }
}
```

Take in mind that only PHP 8.1 or later versions support Enum

Comment: I went along @nuriddin lines, but implemented the method on a base "enum trait", along other utilities. I also preferred going with the enum instance instead of its attributes `$cases[array_rand($cases)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Put all enum values as constants in a class like this:

```
<?php
class Status{
    const ACCEPTED= "accepted";
    const WITH_ERRORS= "with errore";
    const DONE= "done";
    const FAILED='failed';
}


$ref = new ReflectionClass('Status');
$statuses = $ref->getConstants();
print_r(statuses );
```

This should output:

```
Array
(
    ['ACCEPTED'] => accepted
    ['WITH_ERRORS'] => with errors
    ['DONE'] => done
    ['FAILED']=> failed
)
```

Then to choose a random element from the `$statuses` array use [array_rand()](http://php.net/array_rand)

```
echo $statuses[array_rand($statuses)];
```

Of course you could have just added the statuses to an array directly and used `array_rand()` on it instead of defining a whole class with constant, but IMHO this isn't a good approach on the long term.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Enums;
    
    /**
     * PHP 8.1 Enum DataType
     *
     * @author Toni Zeidler
     */
    enum DataType: string {
    
        case ACCEPTED = "accepted";
        case WITH_ERRORS = "with errore";
        case DONE = "done";
        case FAILED ='failed';
    
        public static function getRandomDataTypeName(): string {
          $arr =  array();
          $arrDT = DataType::cases();
    
          for($i = 0; $i < DataType::count(); $i++)
            $arr[$i] = $arrDT[$i]->name;
    
          $i = array_rand($arr, 1);
    
          return $arrDT[$i]->name;
        }
    
        public static function getRandomDataTypeValue(): string {
          $arr =  array();
          $arrDT = DataType::cases();
    
          for($i = 0; $i < DataType::count(); $i++)
            $arr[$i] = $arrDT[$i]->value;
    
          $i = array_rand($arr, 1);
    
          return $arrDT[$i]->value;
        }
        
        public static function count(): int {
          return count(DataType::cases());
        }

        public function toString(): string {
          return match($this){
            self::ACCEPTED => 'Accepted',
            self::WITH_ERRORS => 'With Errors',
            self::DONE  => 'Done',
            self::FAILED  => 'Failed',
            default => '',
          };
        }
    }  


    print(DataType::getRandomDataTypeName());
    
    print(DataType::getRandomDataTypeValue());
    
    ?>
```