# How to get random value from enum class in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, php-8.1

This is my enum class. I want a random value every time from this enum class. I am using the PHP 8.1 enum feature.

```
<?php>

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Enums;

enum Division: string
{
    case BARISAL = 'barisal';
    case CHITTAGONG = 'chittagong';
    case DHAKA = 'dhaka';
    case KHULNA = 'khulna';
    case RAJSHAHI = 'rajshahi';
    case RANGPUR = 'rangpur';
    case MYMENSINGH = 'mymensing';
    case SYLHET = 'sylhet';
}
<?php>
```

Comment: Duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18168360/9636400

Comment: Get the value listing as array, and pick a random element from that? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.listing.php

Comment: $divisions = Division::cases();
        $randomDivision = $divisions[rand(0, count($divisions))];

Comment: Division::cases()[rand(0, count(Division::cases())-1)]